# For concatenation, ColdFusion uses & JavaScript uses +

Tags: coldfusion

Now that I'm on a cf10 server, I'm using cfscript more often.
I had in my JavaScript code some concatenation that used the ampersand operator, when I should have been using the plus sign to concatenate strings.

Are there things that you watch out for when you're toggling back and forth between JavaScript and cfScript?

Comment: Using `key : value` in JS and `key = value` in CF when defining structs

Comment: @duncan you can use colon in CF10+ ;)

Comment: @Henry, is that documented somewhere?  My understanding is that the colon worked in CF8 and 9, but because it was undocumented it was best to use =

Comment: @duncan the colon does not work at all in CF8 & 9

Comment: ah, it probably worked in CFML not CFScript.

Comment: @duncan "Implicit struct now supports use of : (colon) separator" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSf23b27ebc7b554b664dd90601357fb06a77-7ffd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can sense that this question will be closed soon, especially if you add javascript tag and draw a crowd.  :)

There are many differences.  Here are a few.

- associative array ~= struct, but struct keys are all in UPPERCASE by default
- array index starts at 1
- string are not escaped the same way. e.g. `\n` does nothing special in CF
- struct literal can only use `=` for key-value pairs instead of `:` before CF10
- regex difference

Comment: When comparing, you can't use >= in cfscript can you? You still have to use GE,LE,GT,LT,EQ?

Comment: @Phillip `>=` and other operators are available since CF8. :) http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=CFScript_03.html

Comment: However, those operators can't be used outside cfscript, at least not by me.  I get a compile error on <cfif 1 < 2>

Comment: @DanBracuk yes, those operators don't work when u're back to the CFML world.

Answer (score 3):

There is some mention in the docs about CFScript and [differences from JavaScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7ffa.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7ff2):

> **Differences from JavaScript**
>
> Although CFScript and JavaScript are similar, they have several key differences. The following list identifies CFScript features that differ from JavaScript:
>
> - CFScript uses ColdFusion expressions, which are not a superset or a subset of JavaScript expressions. In particular, ColdFusion expressions do not support bitwise operators, and the ColdFusion MOD or % operator operates differently from the corresponding JavaScript % operator: In ColdFusion, the operator does integer arithmetic and ignores fractional parts. ColdFusion expressions also support the EQV, IMP, CONTAINS, and DOES NOT CONTAIN operators that are not supported in JavaScript.
> - Variable declarations (var keyword) are only used in user-defined functions and threads.
> - CFScript is not case sensitive.
> - All statements end with a semicolon, and line breaks in the code are ignored.
> - Assignments are statements, not expressions, and therefore cannot be used in situations that require evaluating the assignment operation.
> - JavaScript objects, such as Window and Document, are not available.
> - Only the ColdFusion server processes CFScript. There is no client-side CFScript.

Comment: Thank you Miguel.  I should always remember to check the docs before I throw something out onto StackOverflow.